# How to create a query in sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a Lessons table:

```
const Lesson = sequelize.define(
  'lesson',
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    date: { type: DataTypes.DATEONLY },
    title: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    status: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER }
  },
  { underscored: true, timestamps: false }
);
```

Which has a belongsToMany relationship to the Teachers table

```
const Teacher = sequelize.define(
  'teacher',
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: { type: DataTypes.STRING }
  },
  { underscored: true, timestamps: false }
);
```

I am trying to make a request to get a list of lessons:

```
const data = await Lesson.findAll({
  include: [
    { model: Teacher, through: { attributes: [] } }
  ],
  order: [['id', 'DESC']],
  limit,
  offset
});
```

How to make a limit on the number of teachers, that is, to accept only those lessons where the number of teachers belonging to this lesson, for example, is equal to 3.

Answer (score 0):

Your query will form something like this

```
    const data = await Lesson.findAll({
      include: [
        { 
          model: Teacher,
          required: true
          attributes: [[Sequelize.literal('(count(teacher.id))')], 'teacherCount']
        }
      ],
      order: [['id', 'DESC']],
      having: {teacherCount: {[Op.gt]: 3}}
      limit: 10,
      offset: 0
    });
```

This  is still a raw code you might want to do some trial and error on your own, basically you want to do a join and get count of teachers from that join once you have it you just want to filter your query using that virtual column you just created.

P.S:  Above code will maybe throw group by error for that you will need to add a `group: ['column_name']` so that non-aggregated columns come along in aggreation query

> Reference for group by:
> https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-group-by/

Lastly, I would suggest writing a raw query first and then finding ways to convert that into sequelize that way you know what is the exact issue that you are facing.